# ssis script task to get file name and creation date

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

How would i go about scripting in VB.Net to bring filename and creation_date of a text file?

I have a variable I have created name FileName to loop over a set of files in a directory. I have another one called FilePath to get the files from that directory. And I have another called created date which I havent used but would need script task to get the file created date along with file name.

Can anyone please tell me how I go about doing this

Answer (score 2):

You can get file creation date using below code.
    Add below namespace under space area.
    using System.IO;

### C# Code:

```
var folderPath="give your folder for getting all files";
 var directory = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            FileInfo[] fileInfo = directory.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfo)
            {
               var fileCreationTime= file.CreationTime;
               var fileName = file.Name;
           }
```

### VB.Net Code:

```
Dim folderPath = "give your folder for getting all files"
Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
Dim fileInfo As FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()
For Each file As FileInfo In fileInfo
    Dim fileCreationTime = file.CreationTime
    Dim fileName=file.Name
Next
```

Comment: Hi user2173966, any idea hot to get just a part of the file name using VB or C#?